# Add values from one column into another column

Tags: sql-server

I have such query:

```
SELECT 
    CurrentAccountID
    , IncomeBYR + IncomeConvertBYR AS AmountBYR
    , IncomeUSD AS AmountUSD
    , [Date] AS ExecutionDate   
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY [Date]
```

[image]

I need to combine AmountBYR and AmountUSD into one column with the same dates.
Result set is something like:

```
CurrentAccountID  AmountTotal  ExecutionDate
3                 2383410.00   2010-02-13
3                 -159     2010-02-13
...               ....          .....
```

Is exist some way to do it in one Select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [UNION ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

Something like

```
SELECT 
    CurrentAccountID
    , IncomeBYR + IncomeConvertBYR AS AmountTotal
    , [Date] AS ExecutionDate   
FROM CTE2
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CurrentAccountID
    , IncomeUSD AS AmountTotal
    , [Date] AS ExecutionDate   
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: Will this result will display data in two row like above Alex asked . I am getting Confuse